# Intersection of 3d Polygon and Grid in Python

Tags: python, geometry, computational-geometry

I want to intersect an arbitrary (but convex) polygon (e.g. a cone in 3d) with a (huge) 3d grid (discrete set of points with same distance in all three dimensions).

That is I need to know all grid points that are in the polygon. A naive custom implementation is very slow for many polygons / huge grids.

Is there any lib that could help (in the worst case it could also be a non-Python lib as long it can do the trick).

Comment: How many faces does the polyhedron have ?

Comment: Only a few dozens.

Comment: Thanks, I know, this is a naive way to accomplish this, but isn't there a great library for this (and much more)?

Comment: Do you have a tool to intersect lines with your polyhedron?  Also, cone's aren't polyhedra, do you mean a polyhedral approximation of a cone?

Comment: Also, is the grid 3d as well?  If so, this is essentially a voxelization problem. https://www.geeks3d.com/20160531/mesh-voxelization/